# Google NLP : row unreadable when the sentiment score is equal to 10

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have a problem when I try to add items to a new dataset to do a sentiment analysis.

I have a sentiment score scale from 0 to 10 and everything works perfectly for sentiment score from 0 to 9 but those associated to 10 can't be read despite the fact that I put maximal sentiment scale to 10.

Is there a special modification to do to my csv file so that google could recognise those rows ?

This is the error I got :

```
Invalid input found at row 2 of ... "Row parsing resulting in unexpected label name."
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You must save and import your .csv file with only two columns: 'text' and 'labels'. Make sure there are no more additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
gs://tttttt-bucket/table_2jpg,table
gs://tttttt-bucket/table_l.png,table
```

You can test a file like this, just give the uri and label. I tested it works.